# NullPointerException with Simultaneous Screencaptures on MAC and PC with Parallel Selenium Tests with TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get screencaptures for failed selenium tests running in parallel on a MAC node and a PC node using selenium grid. The tests run, but fails to create the screencaptures. I'm getting a nullpointerexception. Can someone advise me how to fix this? Thanks.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you are creating an instance of Screenshot the driver is still null so you need to create its instance after the browser has been initialised.

Comment: Can you provide an example/more details? Thanks.

Comment: if you would put debug point in the constructor of the screen shot classes you would see the driver instance to be null. so you need to do lazy initialisation of screenshot objects in your tests.

Comment: what is lazy initialization of objects?

Comment: you removed the relevant code from the post..else i could have explained it better

Comment: Can you comment on this post instead? I modified the code a bit. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195311/code-not-running-if-else-statement-where-it-decides-which-screenshot-class-and-w/38196369#38196369

Comment: Mate it would be best if you can post small sample runnable project to github depicting your issue..going through all of that code is hard..keep code to minimal to depict your issue

Comment: Thanks Mrunal. You helped me figured it out. My folderpath was null that was why the screenshots weren't saving. There was no place to save it to. That fixed it. I focused on webdriver part and forgot about the simple folderpath was wrong. Thanks.