# Not capturing screenshots with Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, screenshot

When the assertion fails it doesn't capture the screenshots. I am running Selenium Grid with Windows as Hub, 1 Windows as Node, and 1 Mac as Node.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Augmenter anymore as RemoteWebDriver now implements TakesScreenshot interface , Have a look here for [RemoteWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java)

Comment: I think I used it without Augmenter and it was failing too.

Comment: It should not. When you say it failed..can you share the logs

Comment: Amrit thank you for that helpful tip. I changed it back to webdriver, but you are right that the webdriver part is working. The bad code was the folderpath was null. I had to rewrite that portion of the code. Now I got the Windows to get a screencapture, but I'm having trouble with creating a folder on the Mac when running the test from my pc via selenium grid. It has to do with permissions to create the folder, but I don't know how to fix it. Do you have any advice on this? Thanks.

Comment: You might need to call file.setExecutable/Readable/Writable(true); where file is your folder created in MAC

Comment: I figured it out. I was using the wrong approach. Whichever machine I'm running the hub on, I must store all the screencaptures on all nodes on the hub. That is why it won't let me create the screenshot folder on the MAC node, because its detecting the path of the hub which is on the PC.